# Why can an element in a vector space with an infinite basis always be in the span of a finite set?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm working on a practice problem that says the following:

> Let $V$ be an $F$-vector space and $X, Y$ infinite bases for $V$. Show that for any $x \in X$ you can find a **finite** $Y_0 \subset Y$ with $x$ in the subspace generated by $Y_0$.

Here's my confusion:

Let $V$ be the space of all polynomials in one variable $t$. I.e. $V = <1,t,t^2,t^3,...>$. Then

\begin{align*}
 X &= \{1+t+t^2+... , t, t^2, t^3, t^4, ...\} \\
Y&= \{1, t, t^2, t^3, ...\}
\end{align*}
are both definitely bases for $V$. But for $x := 1+t+t^2 + ...$ there is definitely not a finite subset of $Y$ with $x$ in its span.

What's wrong with my thinking here?

Comment: Your $x$ is not a polynomial. But...what do you mean by a basis for an infinite dimensional vector space?

Comment: What lulu said.  This "finite" specification is included in the definition of "basis" ... or maybe in the definition of "span" which is used in the definition of "basis".

Comment: @lulu By basis for an infinite-dimensional vector space, I'm referring to a set of elements in that vector space such that the vector space is equal to the span of those elements and whose size (cardinality) is as small as possible.

Comment: @GEdgar why does "finite" have to be included in the definition of basis? This is definitely not immediate to me.

Comment: For a general vector space, infinite sums are not even defined.  In situations where infinite sums *are* defined (say a Banach space), then you can try other definitions of "basis".  So that original one we call a "Hamel basis" and the most common one for Banach spaces we call "Schauder basis".  Maybe you can Google those to learn more.

Comment: Standard is to require that a "basis" means that every vector is a finite sum of scalar multiples of basis vectors.  Infinite sums are not even defined.  seem for example, [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_(linear_algebra))

Answer (score 1):

The relevant definitions reduce to finite sets.  If $V$ is an $F$-vector space, and $S \subseteq V$ is finite, then the *span* of $S$ is the set of all sums $\sum\limits_{v \in S} c_v v$, where $c_v \in F$.

If $S$ is not necessarily finite, then the span of $S$ is the union of the spans of the finite subsets of $S$.

Comment: I'm not sure how this means that $x$ can be represented as a linear combination of *finitely* many $y \in Y$. I agree that the span of Y is equal to the union of the finite subsets of $Y$. However, what's stopping there from being infinitely many of these finite subsets?

Comment: If something is in a union of sets, then it is in one of the sets so..

Answer (score 0):

When you have a look at the proof of the fact that every theorem has a basis you see that every element can be written as a finite sum of basis vectors. So let's have a look at the outline of the proof.

Let $P:=\{S\subset V | S \text{ is linearly independent}\}$ be the set of all linearly independent subsets with partial order "$\subset$". Using the Lemma of Zorn it is possible to prove that there exists a maximal element $M$ in $P$. Now $span_F M=V$, because otherwise there would exist some $x \in V$ which can NOT be written as the finite sum of elements of $M$. But then $M\cup \{x\}$ would be linearly independent because if
\begin{equation}\lambda_0 x+\lambda_1 v_1+...+\lambda_n v_n=0,
\end{equation} then either $\lambda\neq 0$, which by rearranging and the fact that $F$ is a field would imply that $x$ is in the span of $M$, but this is a contradiction. So $\lambda_0=0$, which would then imply $\lambda_i=0$ for all $i$ (because the $v_i$ are linearly independent). So $M\cup \{x\}$ is linearly independent. But this contradicts the maximality of $M$.

So you see that every element of $V$ can be written as a finite sum of elements of a certain set $M$ (because linearly independence is defined via finite sums).